# How to use slicer without seeing other entries?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I would like the user to be able to enter their ID, which will then be filtered by. Without seeing the other available IDs.

I tried to use a slicer with dropdown selection and to cover the dropdown part with white fields, but you see different IDs during the input in the text field and you have to click on yours in the hidden list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Text Filter visual:

[image]

This should fulfil your requirements.